# Azure DevOps Classic Release Pipeline Debug

Tags: azure-devops

I source multiple artifacts in a release pipeline and do multiple transformation before publishing the files to SF Cluster. Is there a way to look/Debug the content just before publishing so I understand my transformation are working correctly. I am thinking to connect to azure storage and publish those file to have a look. Is there a better way to look through the content before publishing?

Also, is there a way to look at locked (secured) variable content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a command line / shell script step and run whatever commands you want to investigate the file system.